# WebDriver: running tests in parallel

Tags: groovy, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I have a system with Web-interface that has login/password authorization. I need to come up with an automated test which involves running 100 tests simultenously. Each test is going to use different username/userpassword pair. For example, user1/PaSsWord1, user2/PaSsWord2, ..., user100/PaSsWord100. After login, a user is supposed to do the same operation.

Due to some reasons, I can't use the system API and unit tests here. I really need to come up with UI-based tests. The type of browser (FF, IE, Chrome) doesn't matter.

So I want to use WebDriver. Say, with Groovy. I have no problems with automating login and executing an operation. And I can easily parametrize them to use different users/passwords. But I'm wondering **how to organize running 100 tests simultaneously on the same machine?**. Is it doable? Are there strategy/methodologies to do this kind of thing that proved to be successful? Any ideas?

Thanks,
Racoon

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not providing any answers here as much as ideas to get you thinking on what can be done.

First, you won't be able to run this test locally.  Think what would happen if you opened 100 tabs in Chrome.  Your system would crash.  Set up a [Selenium hub & Node system](http://brantleytec.blogspot.com/2012/11/selenium-hub-and-node-as-windows-service.html) (called a grid) that can support 100 RemoteWebDriver instances.  Basically the grid is your controller that provides available drivers held by the nodes it's aware of.  [Sauce labs](http://saucelabs.com/home) is one way of doing that.

Now the hard part comes with creating tests that will spawn off that many threads.  Here is some pseudo-code to show the easy way.  I'm not sure what kind of limitations there are for threads though.  Even though you say you want that many, it will probably actually only create 10 or so threads at one time so that probably won't work.

```
public void Test()
{
    threads (100) execute
    {
        try
        {
            spawn new remote web driver instance
            run test
        }
        finally
        { 
            quit driver instance 
            //in finally block since you want the driver to always close 
            //even on assert fails or exceptions
        }
    }
}
```

If you box can handle it, here is a linux/cygwin way of [executing 100 or so scripts at the same time](http://brantleytec.blogspot.com/2010/12/skeleton-parentchild-script.html).  You can write the test as if it was only one test then execute it 100 times in parallel.

Comment: Brantley, thanks! I marked you answer as useful, but not as accepted answer. OK, I got it, no local execution and a way to go to Grid, but I don't fully understand how to run tests when Grid is organized. I need to come up with a solution where I can specify parameters for each test, so that they are to be run under different users. Any idea how to do that?

Comment: Sure, there are several ways you could do that.  You could have a xml, csv or json file with a list of login id/pw's which you could use.  Then write a login helper script that would either grab one randomly, edit the csv to mark the user as "used", or you could use a singleton to store your place in that file.  Getting different users shouldn't be the problem.  Getting them running in parallel I really believe will the the issue.